# jQuery trigger range input field on focusin/focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to catch the focusin and focusout events in a range input field type.

In Firefox 41, Chrome 46, IE 11 and Opera 33 it is working (it is sent to console *in* and *out* respectively) but not in Safari 5. Am I missing something?

HTML

```
<input id="slider" type="range" min="100" max="500" step="10" />
```

Script

```
$('input[type="range"]').on("focusin", function(){
    console.log('in');
}).on("focusout", function(){
    console.log('out');
});
```

Update: Also tested on Mac OS X 10.9 with Safari 7 and was not triggered

Comment: Safari 5 is ancient and has 0.1% market share.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Also tested on Mac OS X 10.9 with Safari 7 and was not triggered

Answer (score 0):

Try inline function trigger like this:

```
<input  id="slider" type="range" min="100" max="500" step="10" onfocusout="myFunction()">
```